# problem serializing/deserializing kendo grid settings

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

Hopefully, someone has a solution.  We have a couple of grids that have custom multi selects on the grid columns.  The issue is that JSON seems to be refusing to properly serialize/deserialize them when there's more than one option selected.
this works:

```
a = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").getOptions();

$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").setOptions(a);
```

however this breaks:

```
a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($("#grid").data("kendoGrid").getOptions()));

$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").setOptions(a);
```

and the annoying part of this is its definitely the serialize part of the equation that's messing up, so it's proving difficult to discover exactly how it was supposed to look vs how it actually looks after being modified.  String comparison is equal.  Any suggestions?

example broke:  Column a has a checkbox dropdown grid filter with three options: 1, 2, 3.  Choosing more than one of them breaks the grid when saved then loaded.  Choosing only one or zero works.

edit:  here's the grid initialization:  Note that DCGrid is an override of kendo grid that sets properties common to all grids such as page size.

```
@(Html.DCGrid<Order>("grid")
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Sort(s => { if (Request.QueryString.Keys.Count == 0) { s.Add(x => x.OrderNum).Ascending(); } })
                .Model(model => model.Id(o => o.ID))
                .PageSize(Settings.DefaultPageSize)
                .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "OrderSearch").Data("getParameters"))
            )
            .Events(e => e.ColumnReorder("onColumnReorder"))
            .Reorderable(r => r.Columns(true))
            .ColumnMenu()
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                if (User.IsInRole("viewOrders"))
                {
                    columns.Template(@<text></text>)
                            .ClientTemplate("#= rowCommandsUndelete(data, true, false) #")
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { reorderable = "false" })
                            .Title("&nbsp;")
                            .Width(86);
                }
                columns.Bound(o => o.OrderNum)
                    .Width(120);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Status.Name)
                    .ClientTemplate("#= clientTemplateOrderStatus(data) #")
                    .Width(120);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Priority.ID).Title("Priority").Width(100)
                    .Filterable(f => f.Multi(true).DataSource(ds => ds.Read(r => r.Action("GetData/Priority", "Support", new { nameField = "PriorityNum" }))).ItemTemplate("kendoGridFilterData.IDTemplate"));
                columns.Bound(o => o.OrderDate)
                    .Width(120);
                columns.Bound(o => o.DueDate)
                    .ClientTemplate("#= clientTemplateDueDate(data) #")
                    .Width(140);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Product.ID)
                    .ClientTemplate("#=ellipseDiv(data.Product.ShortName)#")
                    .Title("Product")
                    .Filterable(f => f.Multi(true).DataSource(ds => ds.Read(r => r.Action("GetData/Product", "Support", new { idField = "ID", nameField = "ShortName" }))).ItemTemplate("kendoGridFilterData.IDTemplate"))
                    .Width(200);
                columns.Bound(o => o.DispatchConfirmNum)
                    .Width(140);
                    .ClientTemplate(CustomGridHelperExtensions.EditTemplate("Origin", "Name") + " #if(drillToValue(data, 'Origin.H2S')) {# <span class='label label-danger margin-left-right-5px'>H2S</span> #}#")
                    .Width(250);
                columns.Bound(o => o.OriginTank.TankNum)
                    .ClientTemplate("<a href='/OriginTanks?OriginId=#=data.OriginID#'>#=ellipseDiv(data.OriginTank.TankNum)#</a>")
                    .Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.OriginBOLNum)
                    .Width(130);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Destination.Name)
                    .ClientTemplate("<a href='/Destinations?id= #=data.DestinationID# '>#=ellipseDiv(data.Destination.Name)#</a>")
                    .Title("Destination")
                    .Width(250);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Carrier.Name)
                    .Title("Carrier")
                    .ClientTemplate("<a href='/carriers?id= #=data.CarrierID# '>#=ellipseDiv(data.Carrier.Name)#</a>")
                    .Width(170);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Driver.FullName)
                    .ClientTemplate("<a href='/Drivers?IDNumber=#=data.Driver.IDNumber# '>#=ellipseDiv(data.Driver.FullName)#</a>")
                    .Width(170);
            })
        )
```

and this is idtemplate (javascript):

```
  IDTemplate: function (e) {
        return "<li><label class='k-label'><input type='checkbox' value='#:data.ID#'/>#:data.Name || data.all#</label></li>";
    }
```

The only options we care about are sort, filter, column visibility, column width, and column location (for rearranging).

Comment: can you show grid initialization with all columns?

Comment: yes.  give me a min to edit the question

Comment: The problem is that `getOptions()` returns many options that is not possible to set with `setOptions()`. I would rephrase your OQ to which option(s) are you trying to change and use only that. Do you think that it is possible?

Comment: i have addendumed the question to list the properties we care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stringify function. For example:

```
let test = {
   label: 'this is label',
   calculate: function(){
     return 2 + 2;
  }
};

let toString = JSON.stringify(test);
console.log(toString); //returns {"label":"this is label"}
```

> - undefined, Functions, and Symbols are not valid JSON values. If any
>   such values are encountered during conversion they are either omitted
>   (when found in an object) or changed to null (when found in an
>   array). JSON.stringify() can return undefined when passing in "pure"
>   values like JSON.stringify(function(){}) or
>   JSON.stringify(undefined).

Resource: [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

You can iterate over columns in loaded options and set properties again, something like this:

```
let optionsObject = JSON.parse(options);
for (let i = 0; i < optionsObject.columns.length; i++) {
    let column = optionsObject.columns[i];
    if (column.field) {
        switch (column.field) {
            case 'field1':
                column.template = kendo.template($('#field-1-template').html());
                break;
            case 'field2':
                column.template = kendo.template($('#field-2-template').html());
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

after you set propertis for columns then set grids options:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").setOptions(optionsObject);
```

Comment: your code pointed me in the correct direction to solve my problem, along with help from a telerik support guru.  Thank you.  The code that was broken was setting the filter directly to the grid's datasource instead of the setOptions, over-complicating things.  The guy who wrote it basically shut off the grid's ability to sync by overriding the events, then set filter, sort, and columns separately.  The way he was setting filters was broken.  My implementationsets them using .setOptions.  I had to keep the existing functions on the columns so that our custom filters weren't broke.